# How to change the installation image to use COM as default console?

Tags: openbsd

I want to avoid attaching keyboard in order to type `set tty com0` in the boot loader during installation.

How to change the image itself to use `com0` as tty by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the image as loop device, mount it, and add lines to `boot.conf`

```
vnconfig -c vnd0 install69.img
mount /dev/vnd0a /mnt/
echo "stty com0 115200" >> /mnt/etc/boot.conf
echo "set tty com0" >> /mnt/etc/boot.conf
umount /mnt/
vnconfig -u vnd0
```